# Xamarin Datapages - Getting XamlParseException

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamlparseexception, xamarin-datapages

I started playing a bit with `Xamarin DataPages`.

I followed the instructions from [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/datapages/) page, and everything compiled, but when I started the application I got a `XamlParseException` upon instanciateing the datapage (`new SessionDataPage();`) :

> Position 7:15. No Property of name StyleClass found

I'm aware that `Datapages` are still in the preview channel, but still - this should work.

---

### **Additional Information:**

**Xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<p:ListDataPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Pages;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Pages"
             x:Class="HoloTour.Pages.SessionDataPage"
              StyleClass="Events" Title="Sessions" >

  <p:ListDataPage.DataSource>
    <p:JsonDataSource Source="http://demo3143189.mockable.io/sessions" />
  </p:ListDataPage.DataSource>

</p:ListDataPage>
```

[image]

StackTrace:

> ```
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue(Object xamlelement, XmlName propertyName, Object value, BindableObject rootElement, INode node, HydratationContext context, IXmlLineInfo lineInfo)
> ```
>
> at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit(ValueNode node, INode parentNode)
>      at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
>      at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
>      at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(BindableObject view, String xaml)
>      at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(BindableObject view, Type callingType)
>      at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TView](TView view, Type callingType)
>      at HoloTour.Pages.SessionDataPage.InitializeComponent()
>      at HoloTour.Pages.SessionDataPage..ctor()
>      at HoloTour.App..ctor()
>      at HoloTour.UWP.MainPage..ctor()
>      at HoloTour.UWP.HoloTour_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage()
>      at HoloTour.UWP.HoloTour_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()

### Edit:

If i remove the `StyleClass` from the Xaml file I get a `TypeLoadException`:

> Method 'CanConvertFrom' in type 'Xamarin.Forms.Pages.JsonSourceConverter' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Pages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Comment: Did you tried to run an example from them? Look up here: https://blog.xamarin.com/scaffolding-xamarin-forms-pages-with-datapages/

Comment: @jzeferino Thanks for your comment. I'll take a look as soon as I get a chance and will update about results.

Comment: @jzeferino the instructions in your link are same as in the link I have posted. However, I did notice that the error I have posted was misleading - it was another error I got while attempting to investigate. I have edited the question to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: Please tell me if this help you https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Pages/DataPage.cs

Comment: @jzeferino Thanks again for your comment. I started going over the code, and Indeed did not saw a data member of `StyleClass` neither in the `Datapage` nor in the `ContentPage' class. However, until I download the source code and go over it in an IDE, I suspect I might be missing something...  As for resolving the issue - Nothing so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was with the references to `Xamarin.Forms` and `Xamarin.Forms.Pages`.

Initially, I have installed the nuget packages as described in the manual using the following commands:

```
Get-Project -all | Install-Package Xamarin.Forms.Pages -Version 2.3.0.107
Get-Project -all | Install-Package Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base -Pre
Get-Project -all | Install-Package Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Light -Pre
```

After this did not work - I went into the `Manage Packages for Solution` (Right click on **Solution** -> **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution**), and updated the packages to the latest version.
I'm sure this is something that will be resolved once `DataPages` are no longer in the preview channel

---

[image]
[image]